# How to update cell value on a existing Excel using sheetJS in Cypress

Tags: cypress, sheetjs

Can anyone help me on how to update a specific cell in an existing excel file using SheetJS in Cypress

Thank you

I am receiving this error:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share the code that you tried along with errors if you faced any.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have. I am having trouble finding the specific cell to edit and update the existing excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select by column and row I assume?

Try this

```
cy.get('.htCore tbody tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(5)')
```

to find the 5th column in the 4th row. Then double click it

```
cy.get('.htCore tbody tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(5)').dblclick()
```

and fill in the data

```
cy.get('.handsontableInputHolder > .handsontableInput').type('blabla');
```

Should work I think.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to convert the Excel file in JSON and converting it back to the excel